# JPA SUM returns long

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using JPA  and I have the following query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT  NEW com.example.model.company (
 SUM (CASE WHEN c.company_description_id = 3 THEN  CAST (c.value AS int) ELSE 0 END )
 FROM Company c 
 GROUP BY c.company_id ")
```

c.value is stored as INT in the database, but JPA returns it as long which is wrong. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here. I just want to return the exact value that is stored in the database. It is a simplified version of my query.

Comment: Using `int` for sum is risky as it could get overflown. It's recommended to use `long`

Comment: Should I change the datatype in database, if yes which one should I use?

Comment: You don't have to change in DB. Simply adjust your java code to use `long` sum result

Comment: I did that, but then I get wrong values

Comment: JPA requires providers to return long results for some when dealing with integral types. 123 should be the same returned as an Int as it is as a Long. How are you getting a wrong value, (what is it, what should it be)? You are also wrapping Sum around a CAST (c.value as Int), so is c.value really an int type column in the database?

Answer (score 3):

According to the JPA spec 4.5.8

> The Java type that is contained in the result of a query using an
> aggregate function is as follows:
>
> • COUNT returns Long.
>
> • MAX, MIN return the type of the state field to which they are applied.
>
> • AVG returns Double.
>
> • SUM returns Long when applied to state fields of
> integral types (other than BigInteger); Double when applied to state
> fields of floating point types; BigInteger when applied to state
> fields of type BigInteger; and BigDecimal when applied to state fields
> of type BigDecimal.

Comment: Is there any way to do type casting of the result when doing JPQL? I have a case where I'm 100% sure the result of sum is never going to be bigger than even 100.

Comment: With plain JPQL it's not possible, you will have to use HQL `cast(sum(..) as integer)` or do the conversion in Java